# Leaflet if statement for mouseout function

Tags: leaflet, geojson, if-statement

I would like to set a separate mouseout conditions for one of the geoJson.property value.

The situation looks as follows:

I set function for

```
function style2(feature) {
if (feature.properties.Post_Survey_Home_Count === "")
    return{
    fillColor: '#ffff99',
    fillOpacity: '#ffff99',
    weight: 0.5
    }
    else
return {
    fillColor: getColor2(feature.properties.Type),
    fillOpacity: 1,
    weight: 2,
    opacity: 0.75,
    //color: '#ffffff',
    //dashArray: '3'
};
}
```

and next in terms of these statements I would like to set a separate mouseout function for this one geoJSON property:

So that I tried:

```
   layer.on({ 
                mouseover: function (e) {
                    this.setStyle({
                        'fillColor': '#663300',
                        'weight':11
                    });
                },
                mouseout: function (e) {
                    if (feature.properties.Post_Survey_Home_Count === ""){
                    this.setStyle({
                        'fillColor':'#ffff99',
                        'weight': 0.5
                    }) else {
                    this.setStyle({
                        'fillColor': getColor2(feature.properties.Type),
                        'weight': 2
                    });
                }
                }
```

But my map is gone.
Console says about unexpected tokens, when I fixed them the console says: Unepxpected "else".

Does it mean, that if statements are not available for the mouseover and mouseout function?

1 - before mouseover
2 - after mouseover - the view back to typical for a whole layer instead of this one property

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe, that much more convenient is to use the `resetStyle` statement.
In this event my code looks as follows:

```
   layer.on({ 
                mouseover: function (e) {
                    this.setStyle({
                        'fillColor': '#663300',
                        'weight':11
                    });
                },
                mouseout: function (e) {
                 job2.resetStyle(this);   //job2 is my GeoJson layer name
                }
            }); //layer.on finish
```